# Desktop PC BIOS: Need to Reset everytime to boot

Tags: boot, bios, reset, cmos

Having issues booting my Desktop PC (Gigabyte motherboard, i5). Everytime I try to boot, it gets stuck at the motherboard logo screen and nothing happens next. But, if I remove the CMOS battery and wait for ~30min, then insert the battery and boot, it resets the BIOS and boots after showing the 'BIOS Resetted" message (which is fine, I don't care). What could be the problem, and what is a permanent solution to this? Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Start in BIOS and then reset the BIOS to default settings.  Save, exit, start up again and see if that helps. Did the above for my own desktop machine.

Comment: Have you tried to replace the BIOS battery? May be battery is just near death and therefore the BIOS memory get partially corrupted which forces you to do the reset.

Answer (score 2):

This definitely sounds like the CMOS battery voltage has decreased past the point of it working properly, or is completely dead.  Replacing it should resolve the issue.  Typically, these are CR2032 (should say on the battery), just find a replacement from just about any store.